# Is it fine to have machine cut chicken or mutton for a muslim living in a non muslim area?

Tags: halal-haram, meat

What are the alternatives when you are in a non muslim country or a country where the muslim population is very less, in a situation where you are tempted by your desires to eat meat but the problem is you don't have halal chicken and mutton, rather you have the machine cut chicken or mutton which is not halal

Is it ok for a muslim to consume such meat because of no options or he should strictly retort to veg in such situations ?

P.S I am only asking about halal chicken and halal mutton not pork as I know it is forbidden strictly.

Comment: What is haram remains haram, regardless of temptation or inconvenience.